# How to express the logical OR in this query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have three nodes: Product, Attributes, ExtraAttributes:

```
MATCH (p:Product {type:'TV'})-[r:HAS_ATTRIBUTES]->(a:Attributes {color:'red'})
```

I want to find TVs with color = red. However, the 'color' attribute may also be stored in the ExtraAttributes node depending on different types of products. So I need to also have a query below to search the possibilities of color in the ExtraAttributes node:

```
MATCH (p:Product {type:'TV'})-[r:HAS_EXTRA_ATTRIBUTES]->(a:ExtraAttributes {color:'red'})
```

How to express this logic on one query?

Comment: Can you standardize your `Attributes` and `ExtraAttributes` nodes so that every property belongs to just one label? That would make your life a lot easier. Or, can you put every "attribute" in its own node?

Comment: My application makes this hard to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (p:Product {type:'TV'})
WHERE (p)-[:HAS_ATTRIBUTES|HAS_EXTRA_ATTRIBUTES]->({color:'red'})
...
```